# create and return a Nodelist after parsing a string with regex

Tags: java, regex, xml, xslt, nodelist

I am attempting to make a java function to use in my stylesheet that will split a string based on a regex character and return a NodeList.

For example, I would like my stylesheet to be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="re:splitRegex('This  is  my      string', '\s\s+')"/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I want my resulting XML to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:stash="xalan://com.nxtech.util.io.Stash">
    <token>This</token>
    <token>is</token>
    <token>my</token>
    <token>string</token>
</Root>
```

I have this function in my java code that returns an array of strings:

```
public static String[] split(String toSplit,String regex) {
    return toSplit.split(regex);
}
```

But I need something that returns a `NodeList`, or whatever will format my XML file correctly.

Comment: Your result doesn't look like XML.

Comment: Sorry about that, I removed the repeating line.

Comment: The repeated lines aren't the only problem, you have also a self-closing root element and all the token tags are out of it.

Comment: I apologize again, I copied and pasted and thought it was self explanatory. I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: As you use XSLT with Java, why can't you use Saxon 9 and pure XSLT/XPath 2.0 to do the job or if you use Xalan then it has EXSLT support built-in http://xalan.apache.org/old/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltStrings.html to achieve that. If you really want to implement that on your own in Java for Xalan then I suppose the Xalan sources for that Exslt function will show how to set it up.

Comment: See http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xalan/java/branches/xalan-j_2_7_1_maint/src/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltStrings.java?view=markup#l198 how the Exslt split is implemented, I guess you can follow that implementation, even if you want to split based on regular expressions and not based on a string with delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Martin, that it is better to do it in *XSLT 2.0*.

But if you prefer the *Xalan / Java* approach, then:

### Solution #1

Change your Java function, so that it returns concatenated
tokens, "enveloped" between `token` tags (opening and closing).

```
`<token>...</token>`
```

(plus `\n` after each `</token>`).

The returned content should be written out between opening and closing
*Root* tags.

### Solution #2

If you for some other reason need a `node-set`, you can do it as follows:

In the `stylesheet` tag include:

```
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
```

Your splitting function should return one concatenated string (as above).

Then, in the proper place write:

```
<xsl:variable name="wrk">
  <xsl:value-of select="re:splitRegex('This  is  my      string', '\s\s+')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="exsl:node-set($wrk)"/>
```

The `node-set` function changes a *Result Tree Fragment* into a "proper" `node-set`
which you can use e.g. in XPaths or in any other way.

Comment: If the function returns a string, then neither of these suggestions will work.